# sparse matrix calculations in scipy

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Sorry for rookie question. I'm learning to work with scipy.sparse and I'm out of ideas why this code does not work. The dimensions are correct but the subtraction can not be computed:

```
c=(count_mat[i]) # c is the ith row of the sparse csr matrix count_mat, it has d #                      elements
l=c.sum()
second_mnt+=(1/(l*(l-1)))*((c.T*c)-spdiags(c,0,d,d))
```

the subtraction between the 2 d*d sparse matrices can not be computed.

EDIT:
The error is exactly in the line calculating the second_mnt. So it is hard to think it's related to anything other than the subtraction between the 2 matrices. This is the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hfjrk/PycharmProjects/Project/my_code_1.py", line 28, in <module>
    second_mnt+=(1/(l*(l-1)))*((c.T*c)-sparse.spdiags(c,0,d,d))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 366, in __sub__
    return self._binopt(other,'_minus_')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 1039, in _binopt
    other = self.__class__(other)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py", line 31, in __init__
    arg1 = arg1.asformat(self.format)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py", line 213, in asformat
    return getattr(self,'to' + format)()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\dia.py", line 237, in tocsc
    return self.tocoo().tocsc()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\coo.py", line 313, in tocsc
    indptr, indices, data)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('bool') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: "the subtraction between the 2 d*d sparse matrices can not be computed"  Do you get an error?  Please show the complete traceback.  It would help if you simplified the code as much as possible.  E.g. if you think the error is in the subtraction, get rid of everything else except the subtraction.

Comment: What is `second_mnt`?  Does it calculate the expression on the right correctly?  In other words, lets determine whether the `+=` is the problem or not.

Comment: Well, I broke the line calculating the second_mnt into 2 lines. first I calculate the subtraction as the variable temp and then next line:  second_mnt+=(1/(l*(l-1)))*temp/ but still the error is in the line calculating temp suggesting it's related to the subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having problems with the

```
spdiags(c,0,d,d)
```

term.  It produces a matrix, which converts to `coo` just fine.  But throws an error when `.todense` or `tocsr`.  Its `data` is an object, not a number or array.

Try this:

```
sparse.spdiags(c.A,0,4,4)
```

In other words, the `data` argument for `spdiags` should be a list or numpy array, not a sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks, That solved the error. it appears that spdiags does not accept a sparse array as input or atleast in the way I was giving it. converting c to dense and passing it to spdiags solved the problem as you suggested.